# Can't see songs on ipod after syncing with rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, ipod

I have Rhythmbox and Ubuntu 17. After syncing the ipod, rhythmbox displays songs on the ipod but when it's disconnected, the ipod states there is no music. Any ideas?

Comment: But does the iPod displaying song before you sync it with Rhythmbox?

Comment: they were showing ok before the sync, yes

Comment: I guess that Rhythmbox is rebuilding the index on Ipod. While it was supported by old Ipod, latest are using signed library. This is probably not possible to get it working.